# How to programmatically respond to Snap in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Is there a way to respond to Snap in C# in a Metro app? When one of the pages is snapped I need to show another one. My idea is to respond to snap by naviating to another page.

I found

```
var currentView = ApplicationLayout.GetForCurrentView();
currentView.LayoutChanged += new TypedEventHandler<ApplicationLayout, ApplicationLayoutChangedEventArgs>(currentView_LayoutChanged);
```

but it looks like it no longer works in Consumer Preview. Is there another way?

Comment: This is covered well in the Snap sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Snap-Sample-2dc21ee3

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated as of the Release Preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Consumer Preview you need to react to a different event. It's ViewStateChanged now, not LayoutChanged.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Check out my post below for Release Preview

Comment: to be fair, it is not wrong FOR CONSUMER PREVIEW which is the first three words of the answer. It is not right for the current version, but that's not the same as being wrong.

Answer (score 24):

In Release Preview you need to react to a different event, again :)
It's SizeChanged now, not ViewStateChanged.

Previously, your app would do something like this to handle view state changes:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

// Register for the viewstatechanged event
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ViewStateChanged += ViewStateChanged;    

private void ViewStateChanged(ApplicationView sender, ApplicationViewStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
     // Obtain view state from event payload
     ApplicationViewState myViewState = e.ViewState; 
}
```

Now apps should do this:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

// Register for the window resize event
Window.Current.SizeChanged += WindowSizeChanged;     

private void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Obtain view state by explicitly querying for it
    ApplicationViewState myViewState = ApplicationView.Value;
}
```

[More info here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/d573295e-926f-4a03-a158-19d4b53521f8)

Answer (score 9):

Jowen had the answer, I'm just adding some more to the WindowSizeChanged code here:

```
    ApplicationViewState viewState = ApplicationView.Value;
    if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.Filled)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is Filled");
    }
    else if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is FullScreenLandscape");
    }
    else if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is Snapped");
    }
    else if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is FullScreenPortrait");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is something unexpected");
    }
```

What I find a little surprising is that when I copied this placeholder code to another page, it gives the code a bounded rectangle and, since I did not have "using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;" yet, when I hovered over the unrecognized code, it asked "Import the file for the pasted code?" I guess it (I don't know if "it" is VS or Resharper) is keeping track of code that has pasted in, as it may be viewed with a rakishly angled or akimbo eyebrow.

Comment: True, that would be preferable.

Comment: 'ApplicationViewState may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, query for window layout sizes directly.' AGAIN OUTDATED.