# VisualStateManager in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-store-apps

I design an application for **Windows RT**. I used `VisualStateManager` for snapped in a *user control*. but when my application snapped the user control is not changed. where is the problem?

```
<Grid  Width="500" Height="40" Margin="15" x:Name="questionRoot" Background="DarkSeaGreen">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

        <TextBlock x:Name="OrginalWord" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding Question.OrginalWord}"></TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait"/>
            <!--
                The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                for the grid displayed in all other view states
            -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OrginalWord" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="88"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method in codebehind? You need to detect when the application transitions from Full/Fill to Snap mode, and call this method then.

You'll find the MSDN documentation for this function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx).

You generally recognize this transition when the size of your `Page` parent control or application `Window` changes. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362566/how-to-programmatically-respond-to-snap-in-windows-8-metro) (look at the answer by Jowen) gives you a code snippet on how to do this by listening to the Window's size changed event.

Comment: thanks for you help, maybe you can answer to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680681/animation-for-control-visibility-in-windows-store-app-windows-8-metro

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue I found a solution that helped me and may be someone find it useful if the usercontrol is hosted in layoutawarepage

```
<my:usercontrole Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates" />
```

otherwise you will have to de the follow (example can be found in the layout aware page)
•make event handler on sizechanged

•in the event handler check the viewstate with ApplicationView.Value

•move to that state with VisualStateManager.GoToState