# Visual states doesn't work Winrt app

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'am creating an winrt app.

But when i create a visual state (by example: snapped)
It just won't work when i debug the app.

Setup of my page:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="Jukebox.Windows8Metro.LoginPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Jukebox.Windows8Metro"
xmlns:common="using:Jukebox.Windows8Metro.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Background="#FF00A99E">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="768">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Let's get started" FontSize="44" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Oswald/Oswald-Bold.ttf#Oswald" Margin="34,285,34,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sign in with a Microsoft account" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Oswald" Margin="0,375,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFED197A" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sign in with a Facebook account" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Oswald" Margin="0,450,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF17AA9E" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sign in" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Oswald" Margin="0,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFED197A" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Image x:Name="image3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="178" Margin="0,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="501" Source="Assets/WideLogoHiresTransparant.png"/>
        <Image x:Name="image2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="53" Margin="0,375,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" Source="Assets/LoginButtons/LoginMS.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="LoginMicrosoft" />
        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="53" Margin="0,450,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" Source="Assets/LoginButtons/LoginFB.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="LoginFacebook" />
        <Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="53" Margin="0,525,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" Source="Assets/LoginButtons/Login.png" Stretch="Fill" Tapped="Login" />
        <ProgressRing x:Name="pgWait" Height="100" Width="100" Foreground="#FFED197A"/>
    </Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard></Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>284.4</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>47.7</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>284.4</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>47.7</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>284.4</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>47.7</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>252</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>60</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="39" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.FontSize)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="image3">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>292</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="image3">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <x:Double>103</x:Double>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="image3">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>0,119,0,0</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="image3">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="pgWait">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>34,252,34,0</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>18,342,18,0</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>18,415,18,0</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>18,488,18,0</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

(The state is generated by recording)
Short: Fort testing i'm doing several things, change width and height from images and change the alignment

What am i missing? I think its a very small thing but i don't know what.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to your question. that way you can mark it as accepted and close your question. You will need to wait to accept it though

Comment: I wanted to answer my question, but i needed to wait 7 hours. (because my reputation is to low ...)

So tomorrow i will copy/paste my solution as an answer.

Comment: I just received some reputation and now i have added it as an answer.
In two days i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this post i solved my problem. 
[How to programmatically respond to Snap in Windows 8 Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362566/how-to-programmatically-respond-to-snap-in-windows-8-metro)

I don't know if it is a good solution, but it works.

So i changed the constructor to this:

```
public LoginPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    // Register for the window resize event
    Window.Current.SizeChanged += WindowSizeChanged;  
}
```

The Window size changed event handles the states and activates the correct state.

```
private void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Obtain view state by explicitly querying for it
    ApplicationViewState viewState = ApplicationView.Value;
    if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.Filled)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is Filled");
    }
    else if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is FullScreenLandscape");
    }
    else if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is Snapped");
        //Activate the Snapped state
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Snapped", true);
    }
    else if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is FullScreenPortrait");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("viewState is something unexpected");
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

there is a better way to solve your problem.
You have to add your visualstate to the layout root (certainly a grid).

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="MyApp.LoginPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Jukebox.Windows8Metro"
    xmlns:common="using:Jukebox.Windows8Metro.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> 
        <Grid x:Name="foo">
            <!--Your stuff-->
        </Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>    
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!--Sample-->
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="foo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

You should avoid to deal with your visual state in code behind.
When you page will change his visual state (to snapped for example) the view will be updated with what you provide in the snapp section (in this sample, nothing will change, you can simple remove "visible" and add "collapsed", and also add one color to the grid to see the changes).

Comment: I was exactly doing that, but my page doesn't trigger automatically that the visual state is changed.

With the code in code behind my page knows that the visual state is changed and updates the layout.

[I updated my question with my complete page.]